# For Which Property Should I Raise the Property Changed Event to Update the List of Orders in a Segment

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have a list of items each of which contain another list of items.  To illustrate in the code below, the code-behind file has a property, "Segments," which is a list of the "Segment" class.  Each instance of the "Segment" class has a property called "Orders" which is itself a list of the "Order" class.  Below is the example of the classes:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public List<Segment> Segments {get; set;}
}

public class Segment
{
  public DateTime Start {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
  public List<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I created an ItemsControl in XAML which has another ItemsControl nexted within as illustrated below and bound the Items controls to the various lists:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Segments}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Grid.Column="0" IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Margin="5">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Start}" />
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding End}" />
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="2" />
                      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OrderDate}" Margin="2" />
                      <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2" />
                    </Grid>
                  </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Initially, I added ten segments with 100 orders each in the constructor of the test app.  Everything displays properly.  However, when I then try to add additional orders over time, the display does not update with the newest orders.  I've tried adding property change notification to the Segments property in the code-behind class as well as the Orders property in the Segment class.  I have also tried making both the Segments property and the Orders property Observable Collections.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) for your collection object should handle the Add/Remove notifications for you. If you're trying to bubble up the notification from an Order to the Segment, you'd need to listen to changes of each segment and handle that, as only add/remove and not change is notified out to the UI.

Comment: Yep, don't reinvent the wheel. ObservableCollection is the tool of choice.

Comment: Do you need an example of how to do this?  Or was my first comment enough of an idea to get you started?

Comment: I changed the Lists to ObservableCollection and everything is working properly.  Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: I would accept your answer but I don't see the check mark to do so.